# Adding an Owin Startup Class in my project gives a SQL Server not found error

Tags: owin

I have added the following startup code for Owin in my Startup.cs file -

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Biosimilia.Startup))]

namespace Biosimilia
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a key in the Web.config file as -

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="Biosimilia.Startup" />
```

When I run the application with the startup file in place, I get the error -

Unable to connect to SQL Server Database.

If I remove the key and the startup file from the project, I get the following error -

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

If I add a key to my web.config to disable to startup discovery as following -

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
```

I get the following error -

```
`No owin.Environment item was found in the context.`
```

I have looked at a lot of posts on the topic here already with no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following line in my web.config >

This was resulting in a SQL Server connection timed out error. Removed this line from the web.config. The OWIN startup.cs class now runs correctly and the issue is resolved.

It appears that when using Identity, we do not need to have the roleManager explicitly enabled in the web.config.